# How to calculate norm

Tags: functional-analysis

I am new to functional Analysis, so please help some one in the following question.
Let $T:(C[0, 1], \| \cdot \|_{\infty}) \to {\mathbb R}$ be defined by $T(f)= \int_{0}^{1} 2xf(x)dx$, for all $f \in C[0, 1]$. How to calculate $\|T\|$?

Comment: You can use the fact that the polynoms approach the continous functions. Hence you only need to calculate $T(x^n)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{gathered}
  \left\| T \right\| = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{f \ne 0} \frac{{\left| {T\left( f \right)} \right|}}
{{{{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }}} = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{f \ne 0} \frac{{\left| {\int\limits_0^1 {2xf\left( x \right)dx} } \right|}}
{{{{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }}} \leqslant \mathop {\sup }\limits_{f \ne 0} \frac{{\int\limits_0^1 {2x\left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|dx} }}
{{{{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }}} \leqslant \mathop {\sup }\limits_{f \ne 0} \frac{{\int\limits_0^1 {2x{{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }dx} }}
{{{{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }}} \hfill \\
   = \int\limits_0^1 {2xdx}  = \left( {{x^2}} \right)_{x = 0}^{x = 1} = 1. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
Let $f_0(x)=1$ for $x\in [0,1]$. Then $f_0\in C[0,1]$ and ${\left\| {{f_0}} \right\|_\infty } = 1$. We have
$$\left\| T \right\| = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{f \ne 0} \frac{{\left| {T\left( f \right)} \right|}}
{{{{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }}} \geqslant \frac{{\left| {T\left( {{f_0}} \right)} \right|}}
{{{{\left\| {{f_0}} \right\|}_\infty }}} = \left| {\int_0^1 {2xdx} } \right| = 1.$$
So $$\left\| T \right\| = 1.$$